# When I wrote this code in the controller folder naming the file 'LoginController.php a parsing warning was signalled

Tags: codeigniter

When I wrote the following code in controller folder, naming the file `LoginController.php`,

```
<?php
class LoginController extends CI_Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('login');
    }
    public function check()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required');
    }
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('login');
    }
    else{}

}
?>
```

the following parsing warning was signalled:

```
-Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in    C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter\application\controllers\LoginController.php on line 14
```

Answer (score 3):

You have written if clause outside the check function it should be like this

```
  <?php      
 public function check() 
 {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','required|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required');
    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
      $this->load->view('login');
    }
    else{} 
  }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your If Else doesnt include in any function... put it in function braces above this way

```
public function check()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','required|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
    $this->load->view('login');
        }
    else{
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have defined if-else out side of the function, add it inside the function

```
  public function check()
  {
     $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','required|valid_email');
     $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required');

     if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
     {
        $this->load->view('login');
     }
     else
     {

     }
  }
```